# NET, build an e-mail queue or attach to an existing one

Tags: email, queue

I have an architectural requirement that can be summarized in the following way:

- A User sends an e-mail to a support e-mail address (support@acme.com)
- The e-mail goes into a Mail Server queue (Exchange, Gmail ...)
- A service listen to this e-mail queue and generate a new record in a database and remove the e-mail from the queue

We are actively working with MSMQ and Azure Service Bus, and I really like the idea of Message queue and I would like to architect the same solution for the e-mails. Is there anything outside or should I create a REST service on top of an existing mail server like Exchange?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I found that the most productive way is to work with a third party synchronization framework called **Zapier**. It allows you to bridge together different platforms, so for example, you can read your Gmail or Exchange mailbox and transform the e-mail into a text message in your dropbox folder, for example.